# rolling out and reading base data in an WP7 app

Tags: c#, .net, windows-phone-7

I'm creating an WP7 app that shows an inspirational text for every day and allows you to mark some of this texts as favorites. You can see the text for today, jump to an day in the calendar oder browse your favorites.

All texts are known prior roll out / installation, I don't want to lazy load them via cloud/web, I want to "install" them together with the app.

How should I store them? Should I use one of the open source databases for WP7 and create all rows on installation? Should I just hardcode them and save the favorites in an IsolatedStorage file?

EDIT: Is it possible to have the read only data in a XML file in the Visual Studio Project and mark it as a ressource? Will this later roll out the file automatically? Does this make sense?

Comment: If it's read-only you don't have to use IsolatedStorage.

Comment: Right, the text data is read only, but the user can mark his favorites, so I have to store which texts/days are his favorites in IsolatedStorage ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your concern is speed of loading / efficiency of reading the files then you'll have to test to see what works best. I'd start with what's simplest to implement and then change if necessary.

What is right for your app will depend on the total size of data and the size of individual pieces of text. As well as considering where you store the data, be sure to also consider the format you store it in as deserialization/parsing is also an overhaed you should consider.

Remember to test this on an actual device as the performance you see on the emulator is not likely to be realistic of what your users will see.

**Update**
If it's readonly data you probably want to add it as multiple content files (set the build Action) within the XAP.
The format of the files and how you divide the data between them will depend on the data and the app.

Having multiple files means you don't have to load all the data at once. (I assume you don't need to do that.) Just open the file you need.

**Update 2**
For an example of loading a resource file from the XAP see:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/08/27/loading-a-static-xml-file-to-your-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx

Comment: ok, but I'm trying here to figure out my options, before I start. I have a big amount of read only data, what is the best practice to roll this out and to access this?

Comment: Ok, I added the data as an XML file (about 500KB maybe I will split it up later) and set Build Action to "Content" and Copy to Output Dir to "Copy always". But when I try to access it in this line: `System.IO.File.OpenRead("Articles.xml")` I get a FileNotFoundException, what do I do wrong?

Comment: @Hinke 500KB sounds huge. Try `XDocument.Load(new Uri("/Articles.xml", UriKind.Relative);`

Comment: That trows the exception: "Cannot find file '/Articles.xml' in the application xap package.", I checked (renamed the xap to zip and opened it) the Articles.xml is there, sitting in the root of the zip.

Comment: @Hinek see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/silverlight_sdk/archive/2010/08/27/loading-a-static-xml-file-to-your-windows-phone-silverlight-app.aspx

Comment: Thanks that worked ... can you add the link to your answer, than I'm happy to accept it :)